# Double-tap tab bar to scroll to top of List / ScrollView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[UIKitTabView Gist](https://gist.github.com/Amzd/2eb5b941865e8c5cccf149e6e07c8810)
This gist integrates UIKit tab view to SwiftUI so that navigation stacks don't get reset when tabs are switched and double tapping on a tab reverts to the root view within a tab.

It doesn't support double tapping on a tab to scroll to the top, like in IG / FB / Twitter.

[Tap tab bar to scroll to top of UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392151/tap-tab-bar-to-scroll-to-top-of-uitableviewcontroller)
I found a couple of solutions in Swift, one example is above. But I wasn't able to get it to work for SwiftUI, I'm guessing there's a syntax difference.

I'm testing with the following (added List to the original example in the Gist)

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        UIKitTabView([
            UIKitTabView.Tab(view: NavView(), title: "ImTab1", image: "heart"),
            UIKitTabView.Tab(view: Text("Second View"), title: "ImTab2", image: "person")
        ])
    }
}

struct NavView: View {
    @State var yOffset: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                    Text("Hello \(i)")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("This page stays when you switch back and forth between tabs (as expected on iOS)")) {
                    Text("Go to detail")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```