# How to get to the deepest viewController in a complex hierarchy

Tags: swift

I have a Hierarchy looking like this:

#### VC Hierarchy

1. UITabBarController

1.1 ViewController with 2 containerViews

1.1.1. UINavigationController

1.1.1.1. UITableViewController

1.1.1.1.1 UITableViewController

1.2 ViewController with 2 containerViews

1.2.1. UINavigationController

1.2.1.1. UITableViewController

1.2.1.1.1 UITableViewController

#### Wanted solution

I want to have the deepest VC PopToRoot when the tabBar is choosen.[This post explains how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58848387/12877341)

I've managed to find the correct VC in debugger, but when writing code to get it, Xcode complains with `Segmentation Fault 11`

#### Code

```swift
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController ) -> Bool {

if tabBarController.selectedViewController === viewController {

if let nc = viewController.children.first(where: { $0.isKind(of: UINavigationController.self)}) as? UINavigationController {

if let handler = nc.children.first(where: { $0.isKind(of: TabBarReselectHandling.self )}) as? TabBarReselectHandling {
handler.handleReselect()
            }
        return true
    }
```

As soon as I comment out the `if let handler` line, Xcode shows error:
 `An internal error occured. Source editor functionality is limited. Attempting to restore...`

This line works for one tabBarItem, but not all, as the two containerViews in VC 1.1 & 1.2 might  be in different order

`let handler = viewController.children[1].children[1] as? TabBarReselectHandling`

Any suggestions on how I can get safely to my deepest VC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **Swift 4** version

```
        if (navigationController?.viewControllers.filter { $0 is YourFirstViewController }.first != nil)

        {
            let dashboardVC = navigationController!.viewControllers.filter { $0 is YourFirstViewController }.first
            navigationController!.popToViewController(dashboardVC!, animated: true)
        }
            
        else if (navigationController?.viewControllers.filter { $0 is YourSecondViewController }.first != nil)
        {
            let dashboardVC = navigationController!.viewControllers.filter { $0 is YourSecondViewController }.first
            navigationController!.popToViewController(dashboardVC!, animated: true)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check for the `selectedIndex` and cast the `viewController` as `UINavigationController` and then perform `popToRootViewController(animated:)` on it to achieve this result.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    if selectedIndex == 0, let navVC = viewController as? UINavigationController { // replace 0 with your value
        navVC.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Note: For this to work, your implementation of `func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController ) -> Bool` method should be removed.